# .htaccess show index of current directory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I can't seem to get to the demo directory index.html

I have this url:

```
http://127.0.0.1/test/facilities/demo/account
```

I want it to show this pages index.html:

```
http://127.0.0.1/test/facilities/demo
```

But it shows this directory:

```
http://127.0.0.1/test/
```

here is my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.html [L]
```

the .htacces file is located in:

```
http://127.0.0.1/test/
```

Thanks!

Comment: Move this .htaccess under  `/test/facilities/demo/`

Comment: I'd need to keep it in the test directory

Comment: Better to clarify your reasons of not placing in correct directory

Comment: If I have it in the test directory I only need one .htaccess file. I literally have hundreds of folders in facility and maintaining would be a nightmare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be able to use this rule in `test/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?[^/]+/?$ $1index.html [L]
```

Comment: Ah I had a typo, corrected now. Test updated rule again.